# How to apply conditional formatting using cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create variable conditional formatting. User will determine range and rules in sheet called CondFormat.

How can I get values from cells (like in which sheet is should be applied)? Colors are used in hex format, so I added "&H" to cells with color (column 4 and 5, saw it on some forum that hex needs to be used with &H). How do I set worksheet from cell value? I wasn't able to fix this line, so I don't know if the rest of my code works (first time using For Next).

[image: Variable Formatting]

```vb
Sub CondForm()
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngStop As Range
Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition
Dim Cond2 As FormatCondition
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Worksheets("CondFormat").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
    
'Remove old conditional formatting
For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
Next

'Set new formatting
Dim x As Integer
For x = 2 To LastRow

    'HOW TO SET THIS WORKSHEET FROM CELL VALUE?
    Ws = Worksheets(Cells(x, 1).Value)
    rngStart = Cells(x, 6).Value
    rngStop = Cells(x, 7).Value
        
    Ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop).FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:= _
      Cells(x, 3).Value
    Ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop).FormatConditions.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 4).Value
    Ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop).FormatConditions.Font.Color = Cells(x, 5).Value
    
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: When you want to set you worksheet you might want to actually set it

"Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Cells(x,1).Value)"

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I got Script out of range on this line

Comment: What value do you have in `Cells(x, 1)`? Is it a **sheet name** of the active workbook? Then, since `rngStart` and `rngStop` ar ranges, they must be `Set`: `Set rngStart = Cells(x, 6)` and `Set rngStop = Cells(x, 7)`. And, what values are in `Cells(x, 4)` and `Cells(x, 5)` cells?

Comment: You can see values on screenshot I included in post. I am trying to get cell values and convert it to range. In column A I have sheet names, so Cells(x,1) is always pointing to sheet name.

Comment: If you do not tag me, I cannot know that you want telling me something (@FaneDuru)... Then, your code is, at least, strange, no offence. I cannot understand only looking to it what exactly you try accomplishing. Please, write **in words** the range address you want using in `Ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop).FormatConditions`. Then `Range("$1")` does not have any meaning in VBA. I cannot understand what exactly you try doing, so, in such circumstances I cannot help.

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry, I just started VBA and I can imagine that my code doesn't make any sense. Thanks for tip with tagging in comments as well. I am trying to create variable conditional formatting. It will be always xlExpression, but range and formula will be variable. So user determines which sheet (column 1), which range (column 6 and 7 - can be corrected to be readable by macro), which formula (column 3) and which conditions (column 4 and 5) will be used in macro. So macro takes sheet from cell(x,1), range from cell(x,6 ) : cell(x,7) and Formula1 from cell(x,3). Is it possible with VBA?

Comment: In order to answer your question I must understand what you want doing. In precise terms. That's why I clearly asked you an example of range address for `Ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop).FormatConditions`. After that, I will better understand what you want. I can obviously see from the code where from your code takes values, but in order to tell you how to proceed I need to **see such a range** to advice about what strings to use in the respective cells... Something like `A2:C100"`, `A1:A50` etc....

Comment: @FaneDuru with range $1 to $1048576 I mean whole sheet. Sometimes user will fill in range A15:B40 (for example).

Comment: Do you understand what you are asking for? Do you understand what resources needs Excel to (only) have formulas in 17179869184  cells, which needs to be calculated all the time? Do you want adding 7 different conditions per each cell? If so, you do not need to build all the time the range to be formatted. Technically you can use `Ws.cells.FormatConditions.Add...`. But you should use `FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count)` for each. Then your so named `HEX` values are strings in the sheet. You need converting them.  And are `config_copy`, `config_standard` etc. named ranges? If not, use "".

Comment: And the above figure must be multiplied by number of all sheets. Then, what about the sheet you try using for configuration? The one shown the picture, I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next scenario. Firstly, run it on a new workbook. The code is adapted to work on **Active workbook**. There must be a sheet named "Config", where the (correct) formulas and HEX colors must exist, another one named "BusDep_cf", able to keep strings based on which the newly applied conditional formatting works. The following code will format only the **used range** of the sheets placed in `arrSh` array:

```
Sub CondForm()
 Dim Ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, rngF As Range, arrSh, El
 
 arrSh = Array("BusDept", "Test") 'place here the sheets name to be formatted

 Set Ws = ActiveSheet 'the "Config" one...
 If Ws.name <> "Config" Then MsgBox "Wrong activate cell..." & vbCrLf & _
                           "Please, activate ""Config"" sheet.", vbInformation, "Wrong sheet activation": Exit Sub
 LastRow = Ws.Range("C" & Ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in Config

Dim x As Long
For Each El In arrSh                  'iterate between the sheets array elements
    Set ws1 = Worksheets(El)    'set the sheet object
    Set rngF = ws1.UsedRange 'set its used range
    With rngF
        .FormatConditions.Delete 'delete the previous format
        For x = 2 To LastRow
                .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:=Ws.cells(x, 3).Value 'add a new format condition
                        
                With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count) 'configure the added condition:
                    .Interior.Color = CLng(cells(x, 4).Value)
                    .Font.Color = CLng(cells(x, 5).Value)
                End With
        Next x
     End With
 Next El
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

I will place a link to a transfer site, where from to download the testing workbook to work with it activated. It contains only 4 conditions, but you can add as many as you need.

Please, test the above suggested solution and send some feedback.

Comment: Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/5q03bv) the testing workbook and use it for your tests. Basically, when you change an option from the cells of A:A column, in sheet "BusDep_cf", the conditional formatting changes the cells aspect in formatted sheets...

Comment: Sorry for late reply (holidays), this works for me! Thank you!